# Firebird on WinCE not working

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, firebird

I created an application for WinCE using Lazarus and Firebird embedded.When I run it on my PC,it works correctly, but when I compile it for `WinCE/arm` and run it on my WinCE device, I become the following

**error:**
`"Can not load Firebird client library fbclient.dll.Check your installation."`

I have this file in the project's directory,but it does not work.
Maybe I must use another version of Firebird embedded or fbclient.dll (for WinCE)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no official WinCE/arm version of the fbclient.dll, nor of fbembed.dll. Most likely you are currently using a Windows/x86 version of fbclient.dll. There is fork for CE of Firebird 1, but that seems to have been abandoned in 2002.

See [FirebirdFaq: Does Firebird work on WinCE?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq334/)

Comment: Yes,i saw this: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq334/ but I do not know how it works...Should I unzip the files in my project's folder?Thanks!

Comment: @stani I don't know Windows CE, so I can't possibly answer that. I also don't know if it includes embedded.

Comment: I used the firebird client from http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq334/ ,but now I become the following error:DBConnection:DoInternalConnect:-unavailable database.Anyone help me?Thanks!

Comment: you need to open the firebird port http://chee-yang.blogspot.ro/2009/06/firebird-deal-with-unavailable-database.html